# Opendaylight Aluminium with mininet torus

Tags: sdn, mininet, opendaylight

I am trying to connect my custom topology to the ODL controller using the command:

```
sudo mn --topo torus,3,3 --controller=remote,ip=$OPENDAYLIGHTIP,port=6653 --switch ovsk,protocols=OpenFlow13
```

However, it gives 100% dropped on the ping test;
[image]

I have installed these features:

```
feature:install odl-openflowplugin-flow-services-rest odl-openflowplugin-app-table-miss-enforcer
```

Could you help me please which features do I need to install? I'm able to run these steps with ODL 0.5.3. I need to update my SDN controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, the L2Switch feature which was responsible for L2 switching is not supporting after the Fluorine version. There is no module for arp handling l2 switching. It may visible to write a code to do L2 forwarding.

P.S Regarding your topo
"This topology has LOOPS and WILL NOT WORK with the default controller or any Ethernet bridge without STP turned on! It can be used with STP, e.g"